# JavaScript shortcut for checking a particular key-value inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, shorthand

I am angular developer, don't know much about JavaScript shorthand methods.

I came across a situation where I need to loop through using for loop in JavaScript.

Assume that I am having an array of Objects like

```
var arr = [{name:'abc', val:1}, {name:'xyz', val:2}, ....];
```

Given a string 'xyz', Is there any JavaScript/Angular shorthand without using for loop to return true if my array of objects hold name as 'xyz' value.

I am looking for a shorthand expression , something like `indexOf` function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `arr.some(o => o.name === "xyz")`

Comment: You can use also 
[find function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
if (arr.filter(function(x) { return x.name === 'xyz'; }).length > 0) { ... }
```

in pre-ES6.

This is a more cumbersome version and of course you could extract your function to have a more readable/flexible version as such:

```
function equaling(attr, value) { 
  return function(obj) {
    return (obj || {})[attr] === value; 
  };
}

if (arr.filter(equaling('name', 'xyz')).length > 0) { ... }
```

You could also use

```
if (arr.some(({ name }) => name === 'xyz')) { ... }
```

with ES6 / ES2015. This basically takes advantage of the most recent language features and is readable, expressive and maintainable without the need to create own functions.

The features mentioned are:

- **`(value) => expression`**: This is an arrow function (shorthand) equivalent of defining function literals and the result is close to the function definition in ES5 (**`function(value) { return expression; }`**) - the difference is that `this` in the arrow function variant is different than `this` in the function variant.
- **`({ name }) => ...`**: This is an object spread expression that allows you to easily de-structure any object into its components (or parts of its components) based on attribute names.

Comment: Thank you so much, great answer and very well explained.

Comment: I would avoid using filter as it will require you to examine the entire array which guarantees your worst case performance each time (item of interest at the end of the array)

Answer (score 1):

No quick shorthand, the shortest and i think quickest solution would be to use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

```
var hasName = arr.some(o => o.name === "xyz")
```

which will be interrupted as soon as one matching element is encountered and would give you either `true` or `false`

Comment: Perfect use case for the some function. Method is succinct, reads well, and does nothing unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through with the angular forEach function to search for it.

```
var matchingIndex = -1;
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item, itemIndex) {
   if(item.name === "xyz"){
      matchingIndex = itemIndex;
   }
});
console.log(matchingIndex);
```

Comment: Its same like for loop , its not shorthand , only thing it is asynchronous loop.

Comment: you should "break" the loop once a match is found. In that case it would at least be functionally equivalent to the "some" array function. Which illustrates the point that this method should only be used if you don't have access to the "some" array function.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use the array "some" function then you should simply construct a basic for loop and test therein.

Avoid using array functions such as "forEach" or "filter" as they will require you to examine the entire array thus guaranteeing worst-case performance every time, even if the item of interest is at the start of your array. Short-circuiting "forEach" of "filter" will require you to do something ugly such as wrapping the function invocation in a try-catch block and then throwing once a match is found (dont do that).

So, if you can't use the "some" function then accept a basic for loop and break as soon as you find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `array.findIndex`. You can create function that checks existence of the element with the specified name:

```
const findByName = (name) => arr.findIndex(elem => elem.name === 'xyz') > -1;
```

And then use it:

```
findByName('xyz')  // true
findByName('wrongName')  // false
```

Check it: https://jsfiddle.net/63ayto1w/1/